# How to copy source code build in docker volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have read docker documents and many articles, but somehow not able to understand standard rpocedure , how I can implement below.
I have a docker volume which I created with docker compose, This docker volume mounts to /var/www/myapp in container. Now I build the code and and want to replace it. I am using below commands which works fine.

`sudo docker cp ./broker/ ai:/var/www/myapp/`

is there any other way? Can I just copy on docker volumes it self, would It work? There can be more then one box, I don`t want to go on every box and run this command.

Answer (score 1):

You should build your source code into an image.  This is doubly true if you're intending to run the same image on multiple systems: if your application is built into a self-contained image, you can just `docker push` the image to a registry and `docker pull` it on the other system, and you're done.  Do not use volumes for your source code.

```
here$ docker build -t registry.example.com/me/image .
here$ docker push registry.example.com/me/image

there$ docker pull registry.example.com/me/image
there$ docker run -d -p 8888:80 registry.example.com/me/image
```

The "registry" here could be something you run yourself, something your cloud provider offers (AWS ECR, Google GCR, ...), or Docker Hub (leave off the `registry.example.com` part).

If your application changes, build and run its unit tests locally, then repeat the `docker build` sequence above to build a new image.  You can also set up your continuous integration system to do this automatically whenever you commit to the source repository.  It is good practice to use a unique tag per build, like a date stamp or the source control ID; if you do this consistently then `docker run ...image:20200706.01` will pull a new image if it needs to.

Volumes are for *data* and are inherently local to the system they run on.  If you've bind-mounted a host directory, you could `scp` it to the other system; if you're using a named volume copying it is much harder.  If you're trying to copy your application source code separately from your Docker image, you're missing one of the major advantages of Docker.

This means, in a local environment, you should also avoid bind-mounting your code into a container.  I've seen several SO questions where the bind mount disagrees with the content in the image in some way (one is in a subdirectory and one not; one has a local package tree that isn't maintained in the other; ...) and so you can easily wind up with an image "but it works on my system"...and you're missing one of the major advantages of Docker.

(If you are thinking about Kubernetes as a long-term deployment system, a registry is pretty much required; a unique tag per build is a really really good idea; and the mechanics of simulating Docker host bind mounts are as complex as the rest of the Kubernetes deployment system together.)